# Match Url path without query string

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to match a path in a Url, but ignoring the querystring.
The regex should include an optional trailing slash before the querystring.

Example urls that should give a valid match:

```
/path/?a=123&b=123

/path?a=123&b=123
```

So the string '/path' should match either of the above urls.

I have tried the following regex: `(/path[^?]+).*`

But this will only match urls like the first example above: `/path/?a=123&b=123`

Any idea how i would go about getting it to match the second example without the trailing slash as well?

Regex is a requirement.

Comment: (/path[?]+|/path/[?]+).*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need for regexp:

```
url.split("?")[0];
```

If you really need it, then try this:

```
\/path\?*.*
```

**EDIT** Actually the most precise regexp should be:

```
^(\/path)(\/?\?{0}|\/?\?{1}.*)$
```

because you want to match either `/path` or `/path/` or `/path?something` or `/path/?something` and nothing else. Note that `?` means "at most one" while `\?` means a question mark.

BTW: What kind of routing library does not handle query strings?? I suggest using something else.

Comment: I should have noted that i am required to use regex. I am using a routing library that uses regex to match urls.

Comment: @JCoder23 Updated one more time

Comment: Im using CasperJS with the PhantomJS webserver module. The web server module is a basic http server (Mongoose), which does not have routing built in. I found a [routing library](https://gist.github.com/trevordixon/3061477) someone wrote for it, that does not support query strings, as in urls will not match if a querystring is appended to the url. So i needed this regex to match a route without the query string, i then patched the routing library to correctly parse out the query string and add it to the request object of the route.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/bJcX3/

```
var re = /(\/?[^?]*?)\?.*/;

var p1 = "/path/to/something/?a=123&b=123";
var p2 = "/path/to/something/else?a=123&b=123";

var p1_matches = p1.match(re);
var p2_matches = p2.match(re);

document.write(p1_matches[1] + "<br>");
document.write(p2_matches[1] + "<br>");
```